# OrchardCMS - Not added content field to custom content type programmatically

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

Create new content type via migration, added to him content field, but they not displayed in dashboard.

Content type view in Dashboard:

[image]

What wrong with my code?

```
    public int UpdateFrom2() {

        var name = "ProductViaCode";
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
            string.Format("{0}Part", name),
                b => b
                    .Attachable()
                    .WithField("ProductId", cfg => cfg
                        .OfType("InputField")
                        .WithDisplayName("Product Id")));

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition(
            name, cfg => cfg
            .WithPart(typeof(CommonPart).Name)
            .WithPart(typeof(AutoroutePart).Name)
            .WithPart(typeof(BodyPart).Name)
            .WithPart(typeof(TitlePart).Name)
            .WithPart(typeof(MenuPart).Name)
            .Creatable()
            .Draftable()
            .Listable()
            .Securable());

        return 3;
    }
```

Comment: It seems you have forgotten to add your `ProductViaCodePart` to your type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Xceno said, you didn't add the part to your content type. However, by doing this it won't show up under the 'Fields' section, but beneath that under the 'Parts' section, under 'ProductViaCode'. This is because you postfixed it with 'Part'.

To make it appear under the 'Fields' section of the **type**, you can add the field to the part with the same name of the type, and then add that part to your type:

```
var name = "ProductViaCode";
    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(

        // Without 'Part' postfix
        name,
            b => b
                .Attachable()
                .WithField("ProductId", cfg => cfg
                    .OfType("InputField")
                    .WithDisplayName("Product Id")));

// Don't forget to add the part to the type
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition(name, cfg => cfg

    .WithPart(name));
```